# prints un expected result when i read from file

Tags: c, gcc

i write a code to read integer from file "out".

```
 #include  <stdio.h>                                               
  int  main()                                                            
   {                                                                 
       FILE  *f1;                                          
       int   number, i=0,a[10];                                              


       f1 = fopen("out", "r");      

       while(!feof(f1)){ //f1 is your pointer to the file opened with fopen()
    fscanf(f1,"%d",&a[i]); //a is  array
    i++;
printf("%d",a[i]);
}
return 0;                                                 

   }
```

the out file has only four values like,

```
1

3

4

5
```

but when i run the program it gives like this

```
13134518624-10740437841345139779220584
```

where i have problem in my code?

Comment: Are you sure `fopen` succeeded?

Comment: @Joe Z yes there is no problem with fopen

Comment: @perreal found your main error below.  You have a second error that you don't check that `fscanf` successfully made a conversion.  You're likely to print the last line twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not printing more items but printing uninitialized values that are larger. Swap the increment and print statements from:

```
i++;
printf("%d",a[i]);
```

to:

```
printf("%d",a[i]);
i++;
```

But you also need to check the return value of the `fscanf`  function, which returns the value of successfully read/extracted items:

```
if (fscanf(f1,"%d",&a[i]) == 1) {
            printf("%d\n",a[i]);
            i++;
}
```

This is because only a failed read attempt will set the eof flag and you are checking for eof after this failed attempt and also after printing a bogus output.

Answer (score 1):

```
fscanf(f1,"%d",&a[i]); //a is  array
    i++;
printf("%d",a[i]);
```

You read a[i] and printed a[i+1]

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!feof(f1))
{
   fscanf(f1,"%d",&a[i]);
   printf("%d",a[i++]);
}
```